# Function generator output voltage

Tags: impedance, function-generator

In a function generator, when I set Zout to be 50 Ohm, and Vpp is 1V. Is this  Vsource, or the Vload when I have a matching load of 50 Ohm?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxDHiJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: On almost every function generator that will be the Vload voltage **when you load it with 50 ohms**. So not 100 ohms as in your schematic !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you set the 50R output impedance on a signal generator, it assumes that the load is also 50R. Therefore, you will get 1 Vpp with a 50R load and 2 Vpp open-circuit.

Some function generators allow you to specify the load impedance, so the SG knows to calculate the correct voltage.

From [Agilent 33220A Manual](http://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/Agilent33220A_FuncGenerator_Tutorial.pdf):

[image]